# calculating $avg value within a given geo polygon

Tags: mongodb, eve

i'm trying to calculate a value within a given polygon:

acutally i'm using this pipeline:

```
    'aggregation': {
        'pipeline': [
            { "$match" : { "location" : "$loc" } },
            { "$group": { "_id": 'Average', "AvgField": { "$avg": "$myavgvalue" }  , "count": {"$sum": 1} } },
        ]
    }
```

but it seems the $match is ignoring the geospatial index.

any idea how i can do this ?

best regards
Harald

Comment: what is $loc? I'd suggest you to update your post along with sample documents. Without supporting information it's next to impossible to find where is problem and how to solve it.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer.  $loc is my geowithin query containing the coordinates from my given polygon

Comment: PLease add some sample documents

Comment: Just to make sure, ere you Eve 0.7-dev? Aggregation support comes with Eve v0.7, which is still in development.

Comment: hi nicola, i am using 0.6.3dev .. all other aggregations are working fine. :-)

Comment: holy shit, i'm so sorry nicola! i used the wrong GET url.. ?where={"$loc": ...} instead of ?aggregation={"$loc": ... } this new aggregations in eve are so damn cool! i love it

Comment: Clearly you defined a `variable` like `var $loc = { "$geoWithin": { .. }}`, so if you want to use the externally declared variable then remove the quotes `""` around it. Notating with `$` prefixed and quoted strings is reserved for references to existing document properties ( right side ) or specific operators ( left side ) in mongodb queries and aggregation operations. So if you want an external variable, then notate correctly: `{ "$match": { "location": $loc } }`. Personally I would not use `$` on external variables, as the resulting mix of code is confusing.

Comment: @HaraldWiesinger I added an answer with the answer to make sure that other people can also find it. Glad you sorted it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `?aggregate={"$loc": ...}` query syntax, so the parser knows it has to invoke the aggregation engine instead of the standard query parser. This example comes straight from the [documentation](http://python-eve.org/features#mongodb-aggregation-framework):

```
$ curl -i http://example.com/posts?aggregate={"$value": 2}
```

Also, make sure the proper geo index has been added to the collection. Eve won't automatically do that for you, unless you explicitly choose to do so by setting `mongo_indexes`.